# bookmark feature opening as a sidebar

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, bookmarks

HI, I have implemented a Bookmark feature in my website, but when I click on the bookmark link from the toolbar, its opening as a new window in a sidebar instead as an new page in mozilla firefox,

It is working accordingly in IE, Can any one please help me in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot change the behavior of your script, because firefox doesn't expose in its JavaScript API for websites a function for creating bookmarks. Firefox only allows you to create a small page, that can be then opened in the sidebar. For that there is an API that you are currently using.

```
window.sidebar.addPanel(title, url, "");
```

If your website was running in a privileged environment (which is the case for firefox addons), it would be possible to use the [bookmarkmanager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Bookmarks).

```
Components.classes["@mozilla.org/browser/nav-bookmarks-service;1"]
          .getService(Components.interfaces.nsINavBookmarksService);
```